# Simple registration form with validation

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx

I am really new to React and I worked on some challenges. I need to mention I did most of the stuff on my own without much dependence on the internet beside what functions do. I'd like to know if I did something wrong in regard to code structure and if there are better ways to achieve what I did.

The purpose of the code is a simple registration form with validation, step by step. At the end, it will complete and a heading will be displayed.

#### App:

```
import "./App.css";
import Card from "./Card";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserInput from "./UserInput";

function App() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState(true);
  const onFirstNameChange = (event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
  };
  const onLastNameChange = (event) => {
    setLastName(event.target.value);
  };
  const onEmailChange = (event) => {
    
    setEmail(event.target.value);
    
  };
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (step === 1 && firstName.trim().length === 0) {
      setError(false);
      return;
    }
    if (step === 2 && lastName.trim().length === 0) {
      setError(false);
      return;
    }
    if (step === 3 && email.trim().length === 0) {
      setError(false);
      return;
    }
    setStep((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue + 1;
    });
  };
  const stepBack = () => {
    if (step === 2 && firstName.trim().length !== 0) {
      setError(true);
      setStep((prevValue) => {
        return prevValue - 1;
      });
    }
    if (step === 3 && lastName.trim().length !== 0) {
      setError(true);
      setStep((prevValue) => {
        return prevValue - 1;
      });
    }
    if (!error) return;
  };
  if(step===4){
    return <h2>Registration Completed !</h2>
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Card>
        <UserInput
          submitHandler={onSubmitHandler}
          onEmailChange={onEmailChange}
          onFirstNameChange={onFirstNameChange}
          onLastNameChange={onLastNameChange}
          stepNum={step}
          value={step === 1 ? firstName : step === 2 ? lastName : email}
        ></UserInput>
        {step > 1 && <button onClick={stepBack}>Back</button>}
        {!error && <label style={{ color: "red" }}> Required !</label>}
      </Card>
      <Card>
        <p>{firstName}</p>
        <p>{lastName}</p>
        <p>{email}</p>
      </Card>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### UserInput:

```
import React from "react";

const UserInput = (props) => {
  const firstNameHolder = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="firstName"
        type="text"
        onChange={props.onFirstNameChange}
        value={props.value}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  const lastNameHolder = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="lastName"
        type="text"
        onChange={props.onLastNameChange}
        value={props.value}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  const emailHolder = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>Email</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="email"
        type="email"
        onChange={props.onEmailChange}
        value={props.value}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={props.submitHandler}>
        {props.stepNum === 1 && firstNameHolder}
        {props.stepNum === 2 && lastNameHolder}
        {props.stepNum === 3 && emailHolder}
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default UserInput;
```

**Card**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from './Card.module.css';

const Card = (props) => {
  return <div className={`${styles.card} ${props.className}`}>{props.children}</div>;
};

export default Card;
```

Card.module.css

```
.card{
    position: center;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make this part of code a little bit shorter, before:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

const onFirstNameChange = (event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value);
  };
  const onLastNameChange = (event) => {
    setLastName(event.target.value);
  };
  const onEmailChange = (event) => {
    
    setEmail(event.target.value);
    
  };
```

after:

```
const initialForm = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: ''
}
...
const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm );

// allways wrap your components functions inside useCallback, to save it's value after rerender
const formChangeHandler = useCallback((event) => {
  // use "prev" param, to make dependences array empty
  setForm((prev) => (
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  ));
}, [])
```

better to use switch/case structure here, and rename numbers to some words, you will get some problems if you will need to add some inputs between 1 and 2

```
{props.stepNum === 1 && firstNameHolder}
{props.stepNum === 2 && lastNameHolder}
{props.stepNum === 3 && emailHolder}
```

for this functions is better to create custom inputField component.
Before:

```
const emailHolder = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>Email</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id="email"
// by the way - don't use email type for input. It had some problems
        type="email"
        onChange={props.onEmailChange}
        value={props.value}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

after:

````
const InputFieldComponent = ({ label, name, type, onChange, value }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <br />
      <input
        id={name}
        type={type}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
)

// and inside ur render

return (
  <InputFieldComponent
    label="Email"
    name="email"
    type="text"
    onChange={formChangeHandler}
    value={form.email}
  />
  <InputFieldComponent
    label="Email"
    name="email"
    type="text"
    onChange={formChangeHandler}
    value={form.email}
  />
)
```
````